# Deserialize enum wrapper

Tags: .net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

EDIT: Made changes to code for it to function correctly server side. Still getting the error:

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'BareCupboard.Models.RecipeIngredient[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'Message', line 1, position 11."

I am successfully deseralizing my server-side code for consumption by the client for normal entity framework models. I have however created a wrapper for my enum to enable server-side interactions to modify the data in the format of drop down lists etc.

Upon desearlizing the enum gets stuck in a self referencing loop, it appears.

What is the correct method to desearlize objects that are created in such a way.

```
public enum ingredientType
{
    grams = 1,
    kilograms = 2,
    millileters = 3,
    liters = 4,
    pinch = 5,
    teaspoon = 6,
    tablespoon = 7,
    whole = 8,
    Cup = 9
}

public class ingredientWrapper
{
    private ingredientType _t;
    public int value
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)_t;
        }
        set
        {
            _t = (ingredientType)value;
        }
    }
    public ingredientType EnumValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _t;
        }
        set
        {
            _t = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator ingredientWrapper(ingredientType i)
    {
        return new ingredientWrapper { EnumValue = i };
    }

    public static implicit operator ingredientType(ingredientWrapper iw)
    {
        return iw.EnumValue;
    }
```

It is deseralized and consumed as such on the client-side:

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Recipe>> GetAll()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _Recipeclient.GetAsync(RecipeServiceUrl);
        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recipe[]>(jsonString);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int value
{
    get
    {
        return value;
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

causes an infinite recursion. You can try this

```
public int value { get; set; }
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, however I made some changes as you can see. Thanks.

Comment: @GenericController It seems that you serialize an object(not an array), but try to deserialize it as an array(`Recipe[]`). Hard to say anything without serialization code.

Comment: are you talking about the Get code in the web api to format the data for the response?